# Can we drop "just" in the sentences like "I took my umbrella just in case."?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, usage

As far as I know, in the sentences like **"I took my umbrella just in case it rains"**, we can drop **"just"**, so:

- **"I took my umbrella just in case it rains"**

and:

- **"I took my umbrella in case it rains"**

are interchangeable. Am I right?

What about the sentences we end with **"just in case"** (the sentences we don't say anything after "just in case") like **"I took my umbrella just in case."**? Can we drop **"just"** in those kinds of sentences too? I guess we can't drop it in those kinds of sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two distinct possibilities:

> I took my umbrella in case it might rain
>
> I took my umbrella just in case

"just in case" is a stock phrase, it means "in the event that something (usually something unwanted) happens".

"in case" simply means "in the event that"

Comment: Thanks. So, can't we say *"I took my umbrella in case."* instead of *"I took my umbrella just in case."*?

Comment: No, it would be incomplete. It would leave the reader wondering "in case what?"

Comment: Thank you again. I'm right that *"I took my umbrella just in case it rains"* and *"I took my umbrella in case it rains"* are interchangeable, aren't I?

Comment: @FireandIce - This happens a lot when the question in your title doesn't match the question in the body of your question – you may get an answer to one or the other but not both.

Comment: @J.R. I have two very related questions. I think I didn't need to open two different topics for them.

Comment: I would say they are interchangeable, but I don't like the present tense, it should be in the past because the main clause is in the past: "in case it rained", or "in case it might rain".